# Get returned URL from wp_remote_post if response code is 302

Tags: ajax, redirect

I'm sending a POST request to an API:

```
    $payload = array('body' => $payload);
    $payload['redirection'] = false;

    $response = wp_remote_post( $settings['webhooks'], $payload );

    do_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/webhooks/response', $response, $record );

    $redirect_to = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $reponse, 'Location' );
```

The API endpoint returns a `302 redirect` to a different URL: `www.you-got-redirected.com`.

How can I access `www.you-got-redirected.com` as a variable in PHP? I'm aware of `wp_remote_retrieve_body` but that's for the contents, not the URL.

I don't want to change the behavior of the API, and the documentation for `wp_remote_post()` says nothing about how to access the contents of the response.

EDIT: tried this but it always returns **empty string**

```
$redirect_to = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $reponse, 'Location' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

In the `$payload` you need to set the default redirection param to 0/false, `$payload['redirection'] = false;`

The location header is empty because it followed through. Then you will be able to get the redirection URL from the Location header. You can see the list of arguments used [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/#user-contributed-notes)

Comment: Thanks for your help! What you propose makes sense and it's documented in the comments, but unfortunately I still get an empty string in return. I've updated my question.